# Avoid IndexError : list index out of range

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600,timeout=1)

while True:

    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    value = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
    print(value)
    print(value[0])
    print(value[1])
    print(value[2])
    print(value[3])
```

this is my code to read a line in serial but sometime the data read from serial doesn't complete

```
[10.2, 27.2, 9.8, 12.6]
10.2
27.2
9.8
12.6
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Serial/RXTX Arduino.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(value[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

how to avoid the indexerror incase i want to assign the value in the array to a variable such as

```
read0 = value[0]
read1 = value[1]
read2 = value[2]
read3 = value[3]
```

Comment: What is your desired output if the line does not contain any data or less data than expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to simply handle the exception and stop populating the variables (after giving them some sentinel value up front). This could be done with something like:

```py
read0, read1, read2, read3 = None, None, None, None
try:
    read0 = value[0]
    read1 = value[1]
    read2 = value[2]
    read3 = value[3]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

If, for example, your `value` only ended up with two entries, the exception would occur on the `read2` assignment and both `read2` and `read3` would still be set to `None`. How you want to handle *that* is unclear so you need to give it some thought.

---

Another solution would be to simply check the length beforehand and handle as a special case a list with less than four items. That would be something like:

```py
read0, read1, read2, read3 = None, None, None, None
if len(value) > 0: read0 = value[0]
if len(value) > 1: read1 = value[1]
if len(value) > 2: read2 = value[2]
if len(value) > 3: read3 = value[3]
```

---

Of course, you could always *leave* the items in the array and use them from there, rather than transferring to to four distinct variables.